# Matplotlib fill area between contour lines where one contour line is made of two disjoint curves

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a function `f` and I would like to color-fill between two contours.
One contour is shown in blue in the figure on the left. The contour consists in two **disjoint** curves. Another contour is shown in green in the middle figure, and consists in a single curve. Both contours are shown together in the final image on the right.
[image]

How can I fill in between these two contours (generated using `ax.contour()`) when one contour is made of two disjoin curves?

## Minimal Working Example

The following code creates the function of interest, generates a grid of values, and then plots and stores the contours.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import apply_along_axis, meshgrid, arange, vstack
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function whose level-sets we are interested in
f = lambda x: x[1]**2 + 3*(x[0]**2)*(x[0]**2 - 1)
f_broadcasted = lambda x: apply_along_axis(f, 1, x)

# Generate grid of (x, y, z) values to plot contour
xlims, ylims = [-2, 2], [-2, 2]
x, y = meshgrid(arange(*xlims, 0.005), arange(*ylims, 0.005))
xys = vstack((x.flatten(), y.flatten())).T
z = f_broadcasted(xys).reshape(x.shape)

# Plot contours
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
contours = ax.contour(x, y, z, levels=[-0.02, 0.02], colors=['forestgreen', 'royalblue'])
plt.show()
```

The output of this is basically similar to the right-most figure above. I tried using

```py
ax.fill_between(*contours[1][0].T, contours[0][1])
```

but the problem is that they have different sizes.

Basically my desired output could be achieved (in an ugly way) by plotting MANY contours

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
contours = ax.contour(x, y, z, levels=np.linspace(-0.02, 0.02, num=1000), colors='black', linestyles='-')
plt.show()
```

but the problem is that this takes quite a while and the final product is not particularly neat.
[image]

Comment: Is there are reason you aren't using `ax.contourf(..., levels=[-0.02, 0.02])` to fill between those two?

Comment: @JohanC I didn't know about `contourf`. I suppose it is equivalent to my solution using `contour` and `np.linspace`. However the big problem with this is that the filled area looks very pixellated. I want it to look smooth as it does when using `fill_between` or equivalent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`contourf`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import apply_along_axis, meshgrid, arange, vstack
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function whose level-sets we are interested in
f = lambda x: x[1]**2 + 3*(x[0]**2)*(x[0]**2 - 1)
f_broadcasted = lambda x: apply_along_axis(f, 1, x)

# Generate grid of (x, y, z) values to plot contour
xlims, ylims = [-2, 2], [-2, 2]
x, y = meshgrid(arange(*xlims, 0.005), arange(*ylims, 0.005))
xys = vstack((x.flatten(), y.flatten())).T
z = f_broadcasted(xys).reshape(x.shape)

# Plot contours
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
contours = ax.contourf(x, y, z, levels=[-0.02, 0.02], colors='forestgreen')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Combining `contour` and `contourf` for a nicer display:

```
contours = ax.contourf(x, y, z, levels=[-0.02, 0.02], colors='forestgreen')
ax.contour(x, y, z, levels=[-0.02, 0.02],
           colors=['forestgreen', 'royalblue'], linestyles=['-'])
```

Output:

[image]

Using the `nchunk` parameter for better antialiasing, still with some artifacts:

```
contours = ax.contourf(x, y, z, levels=[-0.02, 0.02],
                       antialiased=True, nchunk=20,
                       colors='forestgreen')
```

*Thanks to @JohanC for the suggestion.*

[image]

Comment: I like this solution but the problem with it is that the filled area is very pixelated

Comment: There is an `antialiased` parameter but this seems limited, combine both `contourf` and `contour`

Comment: Maybe the `nchunk` parameter can help?

Comment: @JohanC yes it does, thanks for the nice suggestion, but it's not perfect (see update)